# Regex - identify final quote for escaping

Tags: .net, regex

Given the phrase

```
WHERE name='john' OR OR name='o'reilly' OR name='thomas'' OR name='o'reillys''
```

I am trying to escape

- the middle quote of o'reilly
- the final quote of thomas'
- the middle and final quote of o'reillys'

to end up with something like

```
WHERE name='john' or name='o''reilly' OR name='thomas''' OR name='o''reillys'''
```

FTR, I'm using .Net

> var ret = Regex.Replace(myText, myRegexPattern, "''")

The Regex

> \b'\b

seems to work with the apostrophe in the middle of the word but not for the trailing apostrophe.  I've had a play trying to define a regex where the word doesn't start with a ' but ends with one and I've also had a look at Lookbehind, but I'm not sure how I should achieve this.

I'd be grateful any guidance please.

Thx

S

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following minor change to your regex pattern:

```
\b'\b|''
```

Comment: Thx. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to match the apostrophe in thomas'.

Comment: For the text "WHERE name='john' OR OR name='o'reilly' OR name='thomas'' OR name='o'reillys''" it seems have 4 matches - the 's in o'reilly, thomas'', o'reillys, o'reillys''